# Not able to import component in vuejs in codeigniter 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, codeigniter

first i tried to install with npm and  try to import app.js file  screenshot 1

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>       
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/ajax-mail.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/custom.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {  $('.gallery a').lightbox({minSize: 480 }); });
</script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/app.js"></script>
```

app.js file content

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('App', require('./components/App.vue').default); var vue_det = new Vue({
el: '#intro',
mounted:function(){
    
},
beforeCreate:function(){
    this.loading= true;  
},
created:function(){
    this.loading= false;
},
data: {
    message: 'My first VueJS Task',
    loading: false
}
});
```

it give me error
[image]

setp 2 i try same code in footer.php

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>       
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/ajax-mail.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/custom.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {  $('.gallery a').lightbox({minSize: 480 }); });
</script>
<script>        
    Vue.component('App', require('./components/App.vue').default);
    var vue_det = new Vue({
        el: '#intro',
        mounted:function(){                
        },
        beforeCreate:function(){
            this.loading= true;  
        },
        created:function(){
            this.loading= false;
        },
        data: {
            message: 'My first VueJS Task',
            loading: false
        }
    });                
</script>
<!-- <script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/app.js"></script> -->
```

[image]

And after add requirejs cdn

error

[image]

And Another Issue is when i try to display message after loading created
code ex:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>       
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/ajax-mail.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/js/custom.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {  $('.gallery a').lightbox({minSize: 480 }); });
</script>
<script>        
    // Vue.component('App', require('./components/App.vue').default);
    var vue_det = new Vue({
        el: '#intro',
        mounted:function(){                
        },
        beforeCreate:function(){
            this.loading= true;  
        },
        created:function(){
            this.loading= false;
        },
        data: {
            message: 'My first VueJS Task',
            loading: false
        }
    });                
</script>
<!-- <script src="<?php echo base_url().'/theme';?>/app.js"></script> -->
```

html file view

```
  <div id="intro">
    <div v-if="loading">
      Loading...
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

it show me variable name before loading means both is calling v-if and v-else or vue in not load problem it show me this screen

[image]

after vue created

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context. [ask]

Comment: Hiii I am trying to work with vue@2.6.12 in codeigniter 4 with cdn and making seprate file app.js
In which firstly I tried import vue from “vue” this give me error import not found and  then I tried to code  in side the footer.php  and in that  I make seprate component and doing this code 
Vue.component('upload-file', require('./components/UploadFileComponent.vue').default);

Then it give me error require not found so I added requirejs but still not working.

Comment: Please do edit your **question** and provide some code snippet, a [repro] or any kind of debugging starting point.

Comment: i edit my question .so you can check my problems .

Comment: Alright, almost good, please now input written code rather than screenshots and it will be a decently formatted question ! :)

Comment: i edit my question now i have to remove my code snapshot or not  for clear view large question actully i have lots of doubts and i asked in one question?

Comment: Yes, please replace all the code images by text written code. :)

Comment: yes  its look really clear  now , thank you for this approach.

Comment: Can you please tell me where i am making mistake in this code